# How to realign (PostGIS) layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, layers, alignment

I'm trying to realign layers in QGIS. As you can see [here](http://goo.gl/oPllK), the "background" light-blue layer is not aligned with the top layers. I'm working with pgAdmin III and importing PostGIS Layers in QGIS. My SRID is 32632. I tried almost everything but had no luck. Do you have any ideas?

[image: background layers]

[Here](http://goo.gl/1SwC7) are my layers.

[image: Layers image]

Comment: A bit more information is needed: Can you measure the offset in metres? And in what CRS are your layers: all EPSG:32632, or also lat/lon? You might get such an offset if you have older data in Gauss-Krüger with potsdam datum.

Comment: Hi Andre, so the 4 layers in the image were given to me. When I imported them via "Add PostGIS Layers" I noticed that "background" layer had SRID set to 0. pgAdmin said the same thing. I fixed this in pgAdmin as it now says 32632 in the QGIS "Add PostGIS Layers" dialog box (just like the other layers), but apparently this did'nt solve anything. When I explore those tables they all contain exadecimal values (no Lat/Lon). I also have other 2 layers representing phone calls and SMSs as points consisting of lan/lon values from tables I created, but I don't think this is the problem. Am I right?

Comment: The offset is about 220 metres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an offset of around 200 metres, it looks like a missing data shift.

Your target SRS is exactly WGS84, that is +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0

If I create a raster grid with ED50 UTM 32 EPSG:23032, it is shifted 200m to the south and 80m to the west to the WGS84 UTM 32 grid.
The shift parameter of ED50 is +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0

To see which of your layers is right, you can change the project SRS to EPSG:3857, install open layers plugin, load Google or Openstreetmap background and see which layers are well aligned to that.

Most probably the false layers must be assigned to EPSG:23032.
Please do not reproject the data to EPSG:23032, because this will change the coordinates, but will not shift the data. Instead you have to assign that CRS.

On-the-fly-transformation should be switched on.

---

**EDIT**

If the background data is from istat.it, it will most probably be in ED50-UTM32N, according to [this document](http://www.istat.it/it/files/2011/11/Descrizione-dati-Pubblicazionev2.pdf?title=Basi%20territoriali%20e%20variabili%20censuarie%20-%2008/nov/2011%20-%20Descrizione%20dei%20dati.pdf). Here is a small example of the border data in right (green) and wrong (red) CRS:
[image: Borders in WGS84+ED50 UTM32]

Comment: So Andre, in my application I have records such as: INSERT INTO Call VALUES(..., ST_buffer(ST_GeomFromEWKT('srid=32632;POINT(538669,5016683)'), ...)); which store positions of calls and messages. As you can see, I set CRS to 32632 because the tables given to me had that CRS set (apart from "background", as I explained above). If I change CRS as you suggested wouldn't I mess things up? Unfortunately I still feel unconfortable within this field. As to the coordinates of a point, Google Maps tells me goo.gl/LN1kW (see address for coords) and it corresponds to QGIS: 539388,5017988

Comment: So 'background' Layer is displaced from the others. What coordinates do you read for the same crossing in the displaced layer? How did you import the background layer?

Comment: I read 539388,5017988, so they're the same. As of the borders, yes, they're stored as Istat codes. I tried both adding a PostGIS layer, and exporting tables as .shp from pgAdmin and then importing them in QGIS, but nothing changes: "background" remains displaced with respect to the other layers..

Comment: If you download the background data directly from http://www.istat.it/it/archivio/44523, you get shapefiles which identify as EPSG:23032, ED50-UTM32N. What happens if you rightclick on the missplaced "Background" layer in table of content, and "Set CRS for layer" to EPSG:23032?

Comment: I'm going to try it right now, but the project's CRS must be set to which CRS?

Comment: Project can remain, as the other data is correct in WGS84-UTM32

Comment: If I set "background" CRS to ED50 (both EPSG:4230 and IGNF:ED50G) and project's CRS to WGS84-UTM32 the layer is not displayed, nor zooming to layer extent or hitting "Refresh".

Comment: No, not EPSG:4230, that is lat/lon. You must use EPSG:23032. If you don't have that, you have to create a custom CRS with '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs'

Comment: It worked: http://goo.gl/fWUa8! :D My gratitude for your invaluable help will never be enough.. thank you mate, my respect.. You've gained a special mention in my next project: Freefall (http://goo.gl/BTWy8) :)